# Angularjs clear browser cache

Tags: angularjs, caching

Each time i do changes in my Angular template (html file) i need to clear my browser cache and refresh the browser so the changes can be applied. Is there a way to avoid that ?

I'm using Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using server to create dynamic template? Question is very broad without much detail given. Please update relevant details and provide some code pertaining to template

Comment: No i'm using the client side to create dynamic template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the developer tools console open, then press `F1` and select 'Disable Cache (while devtools is open)' (for chrome)

Comment: Follow up on this for my own personal knowledge - is it possible this will be an issue for clients when this is published out for general consumption?